# How can I pipe output of bzip to mysql to restore data directly from bzipped file into a database

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line, pipe, database-restore

For making a dump of a database directly in bz2 format, I tried zipping the dump file directly using pipes, as follows:

```
mysqldump -u userName -p myDataBase | bzip2 -c > myDump.sql.bz2
```

I want to do a similar thing for restore. I can do this using 2 commands as follows:
command 1:

```
bzip2 -d myDump.sql.bz2
```

command 2:

```
mysql -u userName -p myDataBase < myDump.sql
```

Wanted:
Now I want to use the pipes to restore `myDump.sql.bz2` to the database `myDataBase`.

Comment: I wanted to add that your original post has a typo in the first command. It should be: mysqldump -u $userName -p$password $databasename | bzip2 -c > $databasename.tar.bz2

Answer (score 29):

`bzip2 -dc myDump.sql.bz2 | mysql -u userName -p myDatabase` - the -c option to bzip2 makes it send output to stdout, which you're already using when you created the dump.

Comment: `bzcat` is a shortcut for `bzip2 -dc`. If available, you can use it as `bzcat myDump.sql.bz2 | mysql -u userName -p myDatabase`.

Answer (score 16):

try it:

```
bzcat dump.sql.bz2 | mysql -u name -p db
```